# Complex Special Theorem confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Statement:

> Suppose that $V$ is a complex inner product space and $T \in L(V)$. Then $V$
>   has an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors if and only if $T$
>   is normal.

Proof in one direction:

> First suppose that $V$ has an orthonormal basis consisting of
>   eigenvectors of $T$. Then for each element of the eigenvectorish
>   orthonormal basis $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$, we have $Tv_i = λ_iv_i$ where $λ_i$
>   is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $v_i$.
>
> Then obviously the matrix of $T$, $M(T)$ is a  diagonal matrix. Thus
>   $M(T^∗)$ is also a diagonal matrix. Matrix multiplication with
>   diagonal matrices is obviously commutative, which implies that $TT^∗= T^∗T$ and thus $T$ is normal.

I don't understand where was orthogonality of the basis used here? If my basis was not orthogonal then $M(T)$ would also have been a diagonal and so would its adjoint(which is just conjugate transpose) $M(T^*)$. Thus the theorem would no longer be true. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> and so would its adjoint

Nope. This is only true if the basis is orthonormal. If the diagonalizing matrix $P$ of a linear operator $T$ (whose columns are the eigenvectors of $T$) is not unitary, then
$$
T^\dagger = (P^{-1}D_T P)^\dagger = P^\dagger D_T^\dagger(P^{-1})^\dagger = [(P^\dagger)^{-1}]^{-1}D_T^\dagger[(P^{\dagger})^{-1}]
$$
has a different diagonalizing matrix from $T$, because $P\ne (P^\dagger)^{-1}$.

For a concrete example, consider the non-normal linear operator $T$ on $\mathbb R^2$ whose matrix in the standard basis is
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix} 2 &2 \\ -2 & 7\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It has the non-orthogonal eigenbasis $[2,1]$ and $[1,2]$, and diagonalizes to 
$$
D_T = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ -2 & 7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 6\end{bmatrix}.
$$
However, its adjoint in this basis is
$$
D_{T^*} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ 2 & 7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix} -7 & -20 \\ 20 & 34\end{bmatrix},
$$
which notably is not diagonal.

Comment: But the adjoint of a transformation is defined as its conjugate transpose. Once we are in the eigenbasis, the adjoint of this T must be diagonal according to this definition. You seem to be taking the transpose of the original matrix

Comment: @RahulDeora No, the adjoint of the transformation $T$ is the transformation $T^\dagger$ such that $\left<x,Ty\right> = \left<T^\dagger x,y\right>$ for all $x,y$. When expressed in an orthonormal basis, then the matrix representing $T^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of $T$, but *only* in an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Ah yes I think you are right. What would the adjoint be if the basis was not orthogonal then?

Comment: @RahulDeora I show it at the top of the answer. In the basis $P$ where $T$ is diagonal, $T^\dagger = P^\dagger D_T^\dagger (P^\dagger)^{-1}$, where $D_T$ is the diagonal matrix of $T$'s eigenvalues.